# Furnace/thermostat require constant power reset/"reboot"

Tags: thermostat, furnace

I have an AprilaireProgrammable thermostat attached to York furnace?Ac unit.

The set point is usually around 22 degrees, and the room temperature is reading around 20 degrees. The furnace is not coming on.

However, If I go down to the basement, and flip the power switch off and on, the furnace starts, and ru

Comment: Your furnace problem might be migrating to the computer.  Your question was cut off before it was finished.  But seriously, before you turn off the power switch, do you see any flashing lights that might indicate an error on the furnace?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info (e.g. a complete final sentence) before we can help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.